# StandardScaler with make_pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, normalization, pca

If I use `make_pipeline`, do I still need to use `fit` and `transform` functions to fit my model and transform or it will perform these functions itself? 

Also, does `StandardScaler` also perform the normalization or only the scaling?

Explaining the code: I want to apply PCA and later applying normalization with svm.

```html
pca = PCA(n_components=4).fit(X) 
X = pca.transform(X)

# training a linear SVM classifier 5-fold
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

clf = make_pipeline(preprocessing.StandardScaler(), SVC(kernel = 'linear'))
   scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5)
```

Also abit confused what happens if I don't use the `fit` function in the below code:

```html
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

clf = SVC(kernel = 'linear', C = 1)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StandardScaler` does both normalization and scaling.

`cross_val_score()` will fit (transform) your data set for you, so you don't need to call it explicitly.

A bit more common approach would be to put all steps (StandardScale, PCA, SVC) in one pipeline and use `GridSearchCV` for tuning hyperparameters and chosing best parameters (estimators).

Demo:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
        ('scale, StandardScaler()),
        ('reduce_dims', PCA(n_components=4)),
        ('clf', SVC(kernel = 'linear', C = 1))
])

param_grid = dict(reduce_dims__n_components=[4,6,8],
                  clf__C=np.logspace(-4, 1, 6),
                  clf__kernel=['rbf','linear'])

grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3, n_jobs=1, verbose=2)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(grid.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: If you use `StandardScaler` in the pipeline like this, doesn't the `grid.score` function with `X_test` use `X_test` to fit the `StandardScaler` (again) and transform `X_test` with that fit? Usually we want `X_test` to be transformed by the `StandardScaler` fit with the `X_train`. Can this be achieved with `Pipeline`?